# Unity Collider - Box Collider and Mesh Renderer shift after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I am trying to attach a GameObject B to another GameObject A after they collide.

Box Colliders and Rigidbodies are attached to both Objects. Following code enables the Object Merging:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
   collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform,true);
}
```

Otherwise no other script affects the objects

The Object B will be parented to Object A as expected. But right after the collision the Mesh Renderer and the Box Collider are no longer on top of each other. In order to obtain a better idea of the situation I have included pictures [before the collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNh8v.png), [while the collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8j4R4.png) and
[after the collision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSy7b.png).

I also noticed that a lower collision force also leads to a lower shift. Do you have any idea how the Mesh Renderer and Box Collider can still lie on top of each other, after the collision?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parent object B to object A, its local transform gets multiplied by A's translation/rotation/scale. Solution make an object C which is parent of object A that has rotation 0,0,0 and scale 1,1,1, when object A collides with object B, make C a parent of B.

ABC Always Be Colliding

Comment: Thank you vasmos, I wasn't aware of that ;)